# In Mininet, why is the bandwidth between two switches so large?

Tags: mininet

When running Mininet, it is possible to create a new link and to also set the bandwidth. For example: addLink(host, switch, bw=10, delay='5ms'), I just set the bandwidth between switches as 10Mbps using "addLink(switch1,switch2,bw=10,delay='5ms')" . However, I found the bandwidth between switch1 and switch2 is a lot larger than 10Mbps using iperf command. I would appreciate it a lot if someone can help me figure it out.

The full code is below

```
from mininet.topo import Topo
from mininet.net import Mininet
from mininet.node import OVSBridge
from mininet.node import CPULimitedHost
from mininet.link import TCLink
from mininet.util import dumpNodeConnections
from mininet.log import setLogLevel, info
from mininet.cli import CLI

from sys import argv

# It would be nice if we didn't have to do this:
# pylint: disable=arguments-differ

class SingleSwitchTopo( Topo ):
    def build( self ):
        switch1 = self.addSwitch('s1',stp=True)
        switch2 = self.addSwitch('s2',stp=True)
        switch3 = self.addSwitch('s3',stp=True)
        host1 = self.addHost('h1', cpu=.25)
        host2 = self.addHost('h2', cpu=.25)
        host3 = self.addHost('h3', cpu=.25)
        host4 = self.addHost('h4', cpu=.25)
        self.addLink(host2, switch1, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        self.addLink(switch2, switch1, bw=10, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        self.addLink(switch3, switch1, bw=10, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        self.addLink(host4, switch2, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        self.addLink(host1, switch3, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        self.addLink(host3, switch3, loss=0, use_htb=True)
        
def Test():
    "Create network and run simple performance test"
    topo = SingleSwitchTopo()
    net = Mininet( topo=topo,
                   host=CPULimitedHost, link=TCLink,
                   autoStaticArp=False )
    net.start()
    info( "Dumping host connections\n" )
    dumpNodeConnections(net.hosts)
    info( "Testing bandwidth between h1 h2 h3\n" )
    h1, h2= net.getNodeByName('h1', 'h2')
    net.iperf( ( h1, h2 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    h1, h4= net.getNodeByName('h1', 'h4')
    net.iperf( ( h1, h4 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    h2, h4= net.getNodeByName('h2', 'h4')
    net.iperf( ( h2, h4 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    h3, h4= net.getNodeByName('h3', 'h4')
    net.iperf( ( h3, h4 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    h2, h3= net.getNodeByName('h2', 'h3')
    net.iperf( ( h2, h3 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    h3, h1= net.getNodeByName('h3', 'h1')
    net.iperf( ( h3, h1 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    s1, s2 = net.getNodeByName('s1', 's2')
    net.iperf( ( s1, s2 ), l4Type='TCP' )
    CLI(net)
    net.stop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    setLogLevel( 'info' )
    # Prevent test_simpleperf from failing due to packet loss
    Test()
```

[the corresponding running screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lM5X.png)

Answer (score 0):

Switches and hosts are very different in the mininet stack. You can verify this by attempting to enter a secure shell in both of these and you will see a lot of differences.

This partly answers your question. Basically - do NOT rely on the information you are getting from iperf between a pair of switches. Essentially, you are not measuring what you think you are measuring. In your example:

```
net.iperf( ( s1, s2 ), l4Type='TCP' )
```

Here you think you are measuring the capacity between s1 and s2 using iperf. What is actually happening is you are running iperf on s1's loopback (lo) address. Therefore the information you get is misleading. It is related to how mininet and the linux network stack interact with the virtual switches. You can read more about it [here](https://mailman.stanford.edu/pipermail/mininet-discuss/2014-June/004627.html).

If you'd like to measure the link speed between s1 and s2, you're better off attaching a single host with no bandwidth restriction to both of these and then measuring the speed between these two.